# Creating data frame with Mondays of all the month as index

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, datetime

I want to create a data frame with Mondays of every month as index.
Ex:

| Date | blah | blah |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/7/2022. | . | . |
| 11/7/2022 | . | . |
| 18/7/2022 |  |  |
| 25/7/2022. |  |  |

How can I get that using python

Comment: could you be more explicit? What is the pre-existing data? Which format do you want exactly?

Comment: I am not sure you expecting for this to set Date column as index from pandas use this. `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), here setting the number of values to `20` (you could also chose an end date):

```
pd.date_range('2022-07-04', periods=20, freq='7D')
```

or, more automated:

```
pd.date_range('2022-07-01', periods=20, freq='W-MON')
```

as string:

```
pd.date_range('2022-07-01', periods=20, freq='W-MON').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

example:

```
      option1    option2     option3
0  2022-07-04 2022-07-04  04/07/2022
1  2022-07-11 2022-07-11  11/07/2022
2  2022-07-18 2022-07-18  18/07/2022
3  2022-07-25 2022-07-25  25/07/2022
...
16 2022-10-24 2022-10-24  24/10/2022
17 2022-10-31 2022-10-31  31/10/2022
18 2022-11-07 2022-11-07  07/11/2022
19 2022-11-14 2022-11-14  14/11/2022
```